# BSF Sampler. How to process local variable as a parameter for built-in Jmeter function

Tags: javascript, jmeter, beanshell

I have BSF Sampler and the following code inside:

```
param = "valuestring";
result = "${__CustomFunc(param)}";
```

There is some variable `'var'` inside `__CustomFunc`, getting the value from parameter `'param'`.

I want to have `var=="valuestring"`, but currently have `var=="param"`.

I have tried several variants:

- `result = "${__CustomFunc("+param+")}": var=="+param+"`
- `result = "${__CustomFunc"+"("+param+")}": result is just equal to "${__CustomFunc(valuestring)}"` as a string and __CustomFunc is not processed
- `result = "${__CustomFunc(${__eval(param)})}": var=="param"`

note: `result = "${__CustomFunc(valuestring)}"` work just well `(var="valuestring")`

Any suggestions?

Can I somehow process the string `"${__CustomFunc(valuestring)}"` to evaluate `__CustomFunc`?

Comment: Could use some more code tags...

Comment: Did you try ${__CustomFunc(${param})}. I think it could work.

Comment: param is not in Jmeter variables list. It is just local Sampler variable. 
Of course there is a workaround, put the param to be a Jmeter variable in current Sampler and use another one with ${__CustomFunc(${param})} but this way doesn't suite

Comment: workaround figured out above wasn't suitable because i have over 2000 different parameters to be processed with __CustomFunc and so there would be over 2000 jmeter samples to perform.
What i did is i concatenated values of all of parameters this way:
`${__CustomFunc(valuestring1)};${__CustomFunc(valuestring2)};...` and put it into Jmeter vars in the first sample as long string (say to the "longStr" var), also put parameters names to Array and put it into Jmeter vars as well. In the second sample i did `reSolveParams = "${__eval(${longStr})}"` then split  it and associated with paramNamesArray